# Showing an UIAlertView the first time the app is launched only

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

Am I doing something wrong in getting an UIAlertView to play the first time only?  In my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, my MainViewController  gets instantiated.  So in MainViewController's viewDidLoad, I do this:

```
BOOL shouldAlert = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"ShowAlert"];
if (!shouldAlert) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyAlert" message:@"Some text here" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"ShowAlert"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

When I try it on the device, it doesn't work if I double tap home, and hit the minus sign next to the app to remove it from the background mode (I think that's what double tapping does right?).  Cause after I do that, the pop up appears again.  If I don't do that, than the alert only shows once.  Is this expected behavior?  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Does it work? If so, you're probably not doing anything wrong. It looks good from here, except that your `shouldAlert` variable doesn't read well. Personally, I would change it to `hasOpenedPreviously`, or leave the name and invert all of your booleans.

Comment: @Patrick Perini No it doesn't work since when I double tap home, then delete the app from background mode, the alert pops back up.  I should add that to my post.

Comment: That's weird, as terminating the app shouldn't mess with `NSUserDefaults`. I would try some log statements regarding `NSUserDefaults`, to get more information about whether or not your boolean is sticking

Comment: @PatrickPerini I logged the BOOL before and after I set it and it is in fact 0, 1 as one would expect.  But I still don't know why terminating the app would change that value.  I thought that was the point of NSUserDefaults unless I need to set it from a different area of my app?  Like can you only do this in the appDelegate?

Comment: Does terminating the app change the value? There's also nothing that says you have to use NSUserDefaults in your App Delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Try with an integer (0 / 1). I had some problems too with BOOL.

```
setInteger:forKey:
integerForKey:
```

**EDIT**
Try updating the defaults before initing/showing the alert.
And please, update your variable names. Your code is a nonsense with their current name.

Try this :

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL hasAlreadyBeenLaunched = [defaults boolForKey:@"HasAlreadyBeenLaunched"];

if (!hasAlreadyBeenLaunched) {
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"HasAlreadyBeenLaunched"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyAlert" message:@"Some text here" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you get your shouldAlert first time from userdefauls? 
I think you should check if the userdefaults exists else your bool is NO or FALSE
check this example:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
shouldAlert = YES; // define in the .h
if(userDef)
shouldAlert = [userDef boolForKey:@"ShowAlert"];
```

Comment: That's crazy wordy, and shouldn't matter. This is especially irrelevant, because she can (accurately) log the return value for `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"ShowAlert"];`